# What repercussions would there be if the Trump Campaign was found to have links with Russia?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

On Monday, FBI Director James Comey confirmed that the FBI is investigating possible collusion/co-ordination (places are switching between collusion and co-ordination) between the Trump campaign and Russian authorities during the 2016 election campaign.

If this was found to be true would there be any repercussions for the Trump Administration?  Would it make a difference if President Trump knew of this collusion/co-ordination or not? Or even if he was knowingly apart of it?

NOTE: in the *"Questions that may already have your answer"* section I saw [this question *"What happens if President Trump has been found to be colluding with Russia?"*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/16499/9573) but the question asks about Trump's own involvement. it is my understanding that the FBI investigation is on the campaign and thus on the campaign team which includes Trump but not discounting the possibility that Trump was unaware of said collusion/co-ordination (thus the amending questions).

Comment: Depends how serious the matter is and if it impacted national security. I would assume impeachment but that's unlikely as both houses are controlled by Republicans.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the people on the campaign, those in the know, could go to jail, if they conspired in illegal acts (e.g. hacking the DNC).  Donald Trump could be impeached if he knew.  If he did not know, then he wouldn't be part of the conspiracy and could not be impeached for that.

It could weaken him politically.  There is almost certainly going to be an emoluments clause fig leaf that could be used to impeach him.  That simply requires him to accept foreign money at one of his businesses at the same time as that foreigner receives some policy consideration.  So even if he didn't know, it might weaken him enough that he could be impeached for an emoluments clause violation.  However, he'd need to become much less popular with Republicans first.

It might lead to him losing the election in 2020, even if not impeached.  It would likely make it more difficult for him to accomplish things legislatively.  He'd lose influence with Republican legislators if he stopped being popular with voters.

Comment: emoluments clause bars us officials from receiving foreign **govt** money in business transactions